# Unity, C#. How to get the all the children of a parent on runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, block, puzzle

I am making a puzzle using drag & drop in unity. The puzzle piece is like Tetris-piece, each puzzle piece is composed of a group of cubes. the puzzle piece needs to be dragged and then dropped into the slots of missing cubes of the structure(e.g. rectangle).

[Screenshot of the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HCab.png)

The screenshot above illustrates that I have a group of cubes named "block1" that has 3 children/cubes, it also illustrates that the game has slots wherein the cubes needs to be dropped. When I drag "block1" and then dropped into the slots it only occupies one slot knowing that it has 3 cubes. What I want is when I dropped the  "block1" (which has 3 three cubes) into the slots I want each cube to occupy each of the slot (3 slots). So, what I think I need to do is to get only the children of block1 when I dropped it on the slots. When I drag it I drag a group but when I dropped only the children will get so that every cube will fill a slot. My question is, how to get all the children of the block1 on dropped? In my slothandler scipt it gets the whole block/piece. Thanks in advance!

Here's the SlotHandler Script

```html
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SlotHandler : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler{ 
 

 public GameObject item {
  get {
   if(transform.childCount>0){
    return transform.GetChild (0).gameObject;
   }
   return null;
  }
 }

 #region IDropHandler implementation
 public void OnDrop (PointerEventData eventData)
 {
  if(!item){
   DragHandler.piece.transform.SetParent (transform);
  }
 }
 #endregion
}
```

and the DragHandler Script

```html
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class DragHandler : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler{

 public static GameObject piece;
 Vector3 startPosition;
 Transform startParent;


 #region IBeginDragHandler implementation

 public void OnBeginDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
 {
  
  piece = gameObject;
  startPosition = transform.position;
  startParent = transform.parent;
  GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = false;

 }

 #region IDragHandler implementation

 public void OnDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
 {
  transform.position = eventData.position;

 }

 #endregion

 #region IEndDragHandler implementation

 public void OnEndDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
 {
  piece = null;
  GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = false;
  if(transform.parent == startParent){
   transform.position = startPosition;
   GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = true;
  }
 }

 #endregion



}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add colliders to the slots, and in the collision listener, check if it's completely in place, and then change the parent like this:

```
transform.parent = [Parent Slot GameObject or Transform]
```

but if you are gonna go your way, still it's ok.I'm not an expert in this kind of game, so ...
but the main code stays still. change the parent with the one line code above.

if you want the cube to have no parent at all, you can say:

```
transform.parent = null;
```

or if you have a parent object for all of these, as I say in your screenshot(blocks, panel or canvas), you can add that as a public object to script and make that the parent.

```
public GameObject parent;

...

// when you wanna ungroup the objects
transform.parent = parent;
```

Comment: sorry but when I do "transform.parent = parent" it has an error saying that "Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'UnityEngine.GameTransform'. How can I solve that? I just want to ungroup the block

Comment: transform.parent = parent.transform

Comment: or you can get the transform as a public variable. change the public var to 'public Transform parent'